# Change directive value from controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive which is used in three different scopes in controller. Now i want to call a function in one directive it will change the value in other directives.

```
// HTML 
<my-directive instance-type="obj1"></my-directive>
<my-directive instance-type="obj2"></my-directive>
<my-directive instance-type="obj3"></my-directive>

// Directive
    return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    controller: '=instanceType'
                },
                templateUrl: 'app/pages/class/templates/list.html',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                    // Bind controller value
                    scope.currentId = scope.controller.currentId;
                    scope.nav = function(newId) {
                          scope.controller.nav(newId);
                    };
}


// Controller
$scope.obj1 = {};
$scope.obj2 = {};
$scope.obj3 = {};
$scope.obj1.nav = function(newId){$scope.obj2.currentId = newId;}
```

In the above code, when i call `nav` function in directive 1 the variable `currentId` in directive 2 doesn't change.

How to overcome this problem?

Comment: Please create a plunker.

Comment: use scope.$apply(); in the bottom of link: function

Comment: Since you are using isolate scope, the value does not change in the second directive. You have 2 options. Either remove the isolate scope or use a service to share the state between directives if you really need isolate scope in your directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var id1 = 1;
var id2 = 2;

id1 = 3;

// What do you expect to print for id2 variable? Does it change? No.
alert(id2);
```

Just like above example, your `scope.currentId` is a primitive type. When `scope.controller.currentId` value changes for obj2 directive through `function(newId){$scope.obj2.currentId = newId;}` , there is no chance that `scope.currentId` will get updated unless the directive loads again.

In this case, you can do two things:

1. You can remove `scope.currentId` and use `scope.controller` directly for currentId.
2. You can watch `controller.currentId` in the directive and set the new value to `scope.currentId`.

```
scope.$watch('controller.currentId', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    scope.currentId = newValue;
})
```

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fv5cXln4VL8He4MycHZm?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

You can use $watch in your directive

```
scope.$watch('trigerVariable', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    //change your variable
}, true);
```

When you trigerVariable changed in controller it triger this directive code.